# Cannot create any viewmodels in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

i am creating an app for my school. When i try to intialize any viewModel whatsoever my app crashes and gives this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: be.example.spacetracker, PID: 10985
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class be.example.spacetracker.viewmodel.RocketsViewModel
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:324)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:306)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:280)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:156)
                                                                                                        at be.thijsgeeraert.spacetracker.ui.screen.RocketScreenKt.RocketScreen(RocketScreen.kt:103)
                                                                                                        at be.thijsgeeraert.spacetracker.ComposableSingletons$SpaceTrackerKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(SpaceTracker.kt:49)
                                                                                                        at be.thijsgeeraert.spacetracker.ComposableSingletons$SpaceTrackerKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(SpaceTracker.kt:48)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:129)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:113)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
... (this error continues for a while)

 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: be.example.spacetracker.viewmodel.RocketsViewModel.<init> []
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
                                                                                                        ... 219 more
```

This is the code of my viewmodel

```
class RocketsViewModel(private val rocketRepository : RocketRepository) : ViewModel(){

    var rocketUiState: RocketUiState by mutableStateOf(RocketUiState.Loading)
        private set

    init {
        Log.d("debug","HulpInInit")
        getRockets()
    }


     fun getRockets() {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            rocketUiState = RocketUiState.Loading

            rocketUiState = try {
                RocketUiState.Success(rocketRepository.getAllRockets())
            } catch (e: IOException){
                RocketUiState.Error
            } catch (e: HttpException){
                RocketUiState.Error
            }

        }
}
```

And this is were i call my viewmodel

```
@Composable
fun RocketScreen( modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Log.d("debug","hulpbeforecreationvm")
    val viewModel : RocketsViewModel = viewModel()
    Log.d("debug","hulpbeforecreationui")
    val rocketUiState: RocketUiState = viewModel.rocketUiState

    when (rocketUiState) {
        is RocketUiState.Loading -> LoadingScreen(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize())
        is RocketUiState.Success -> ResultScreen(response = rocketUiState.response, modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize())
        is RocketUiState.Error -> ErrorScreen(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize())
    }
}
```

the last log i see is hulpbeforecreationvm so it alway crashes on the first line starting with val
It never manages to reach the hulpininit (in the viewmodel).
I have been debugging this for the last 6 hours and cant manage to fix it.

these are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-geometry-android:1.5.4")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    // Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
// Retrofit with Scalar Converter
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

}
```

Comment: Can you post the `viewModel()` method ? How are you obtaining the viewmodel ?

Comment: i get it from a package: import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel.
Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, i worked with an factory.
This was necessary because i was working with an repository.

```
companion object {
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as SpaceApplication)
                val rocketRepository = application.container.rocketRepository
                RocketsViewModel(rocketRepository = rocketRepository)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i got another error (castException). But that was cus i forgot to add the myapplication name in my manifest.xml

```
android:name=".SpaceApplication"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).